# Transform an atomic vector to list (inverse of purrr::simplify())

Tags: r, list, purrr, simplify, accumulate

TLDR:
I need a simple way to transform `c(a = 1, a = 3, a = 6)` into `list(c(a = 1), c(a = 3), c(a = 6))`.

Longer version:
I am using the function `purrr::accumulate()`, where the output of *each* element is an atomic vector of length greater or equal to one. When the length is one, `purrr::accumulate()` simplifies the *whole* output to an atomic vector, instead of a list.

Is there a simple way to undo or avoid this? Unfortunately, `as.list()` does not give me what I want.

Simple example to illustrate:

```
purrr::accumulate(2:3, `+`, .init = c(a=1, b=2))
```

gives me

```
list(c(a = 1, b = 2), c(a = 3, b = 4), c(a = 6, b = 7))
```

as expected. However,

```
purrr::accumulate(2:3, `+`, .init = c(a=1))
```

gives me

```
c(a = 1, a = 3, a = 6)
```

when I instead want

```
list(c(a = 1), c(a = 3), c(a = 6))
```

Comment: It seems that `accumulate` behavior is inconsistent. You should raise an issue to the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
c(a = 1, a = 3, a = 6) %>% map(~setNames(.x, nm = "a")) 

$a
a 
1 

$a
a 
3 

$a
a 
6
```

or you can also remove the list names with `set_names()`

```
c(a = 1, a = 3, a = 6) %>% map(~setNames(.x, nm = "a")) %>% 
  set_names("")

[[1]]
a 
1 

[[2]]
a 
3 

[[3]]
a 
6
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar.

`c(a = 1, a = 3, a = 6) %>% (function(x) if (is.atomic(x)) purrr::imap(x, setNames) %>% unname() else x)`